# Example of a saturated measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We know that every sigma finiye measure is saturated but converse is not true..
To prove the converse part , I need a counter example . Can anyone suggest an example of a saturated measure which is not sigma finite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the counting measure on $(\Bbb R, 2^{\Bbb R})$. It is not $\sigma$-finite, but it is saturated (since any set is measurable).

Comment: Thank you for consideration

Comment: You're welcome. Does that answer your question, or is something still unclear?

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: OK. :-) You can then manually accept my answer in order to show for others that your question has been resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get how to accept manually

Comment: Just click on the green checkmark. ;-)